# Script to auto forward (BCC) message to contact group

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script that will forward the latest message in any thread with a particular label ('send-to-test') to a specific group of contacts ('fwd-test'). I based it heavily on [StackExchange: How can I automatically forward Gmail emails when a label is applied?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95916/how-can-i-automatically-forward-gmail-emails-when-a-label-is-applied)

The script I've come up with so far is below:

```
function autofwd() {

  //target mail label 
  var inlabel = 'send-to-test';
  Logger.log("Target mail label is: " + inlabel);
  //processed mail label
  var outlabel = 'sent-to-test';
  Logger.log("processed mail label is: " + outlabel);
  //Retrieve contacts list to fwd to
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('fwd-test');
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);
  var email = new String();
  for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
    email = contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail() + ',' + email;  
  Logger.log("email address list is: " + email);
  //Find message threads matching the label variable and do something to each one
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + inlabel);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      //isolate the last message in the thread and forward it using bcc field
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    Logger.log("Working on message: " + messages);
    messages[messages.length - 1].forward({bcc: email});
    // add 'sent' label and remove 'send' label
    var addlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(outlabel);
     addlabel.addToThread(threads[i]);
    var notlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(inlabel);
     notlabel.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
  }
}
```

The issue is I want to forward the emails as BCC, but I cant get that line of code to work:

`messages[messages.length - 1].forward({bcc: email});`

fails with the error `Invalid email: [object Object] (line 22, file "Code")`

But it works fine if I just use `messages[messages.length - 1].forward(email);`

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From :

```
messages[messages.length - 1].forward({bcc: email});
```

#### To :

```
messages[messages.length - 1].forward("", {bcc: email});
```

#### Reference :

- [forward(recipient, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forwardrecipient-options)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @JTL16571 Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.